# LinkedIn Share API creates a share but returns error 500

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm asking this question on SO, since LinkedIn support is officially [moved here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/53170/using-stackoverflow-for-api-support?lang=en).

I'm receiving HTTP 500 response from LinkedIn API endpoint while trying to create a share. This happens sporadically, but it is a quite often event last week or two. The weird part is that the share being created successfully.

Please advise. Could it be caused by spiking users activity on social media due to COVID19?

For the reference, here is request body POST-ed to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares (real ids are replaced).

```
{
  "owner": "urn:li:organization:111111",
  "text": {
    "text": "Text text text"
  },
  "content": {
    "contentEntities": [
      {
        "entity": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:111111"
      }
    ],
    "shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE"
  },
  "distribution": {
    "linkedInDistributionTarget": {
      "connectionsOnly": false,
      "visibleToGuest": true
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "message": "Internal Server Error",
  "status": 500
}
```

Comment: What's the URL you are sharing?  There are several reasons why you may get a 500, for instance, if your site is 100% JS, etc..

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Thank you for the response! Here are some examples: https://gist.github.com/dreikanter/ebda3f355a169c94ab8f950209cd0f12 Is there a way to get specific reason of the publication failure in this scenario? Or may be it is possible to validate a link before publication?